# renaming a variable name in php at runtime

Tags: php, arrays, variables, simplexml, renaming

I am trying to convert an xml document into an associative array.
I want the name of the array to be the root node in the xml document.
I get this information by `$xml->getName()` .

I thought of creating an empty array using this statement, but it does not work.

```
$($xml->getName()) = array();
```

Other way should be creating a temp variable and renaming it with `$xml->getName()`. Is there a way I can do this in PHP?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems unlikely to be a good idea...

Comment: I agree with @lonesomeday, but nevertheless: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create it this way:

```
${$xml->getName()} = array();
```

You may also wish to validate the name to ensure it meets PHP variable name standards to avoid a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

George is right, `${$xml->getName()} = array();` will allow you to do basically what you're asking for.

As lonesomeday suggested, this is a bad idea. You're best off wrapping all of that functionality in a function and simply returning it to some greater context. If you're not comfortable, make it a key in an array. Here's the problem though:

1. You **can't** abstract this functionality -- imagine that you want this to be a part of a function or a class (which you should be thinking of *anyway*), how would you have the class/context of the calling function know that $root is now a reference to your XML?
2. You **can't** load more than one file in a script, if you have two files which start with `<root>`, they will kill each other (this will even prevent use of array keys).
3. This **will** lead to debug issues. At a bare minimum, you will need to make sure that there are no issues in the XML syntax as well as the PHP syntax. That leads to increased time in debug & maintenance cycles and therefore technical bloat.
4. Definitionally, it is **destructive** and **unexpected** behavior -- it effects its environment in ways which are not immediately apparent to the next programmer and it has the potential to unset variables which some other programmer has set.